# Vehicle GPS tracking for Atmel AVR

Tags: c++, gps, gis, tracking, atmel

I have made the circuitry for Vehicle tracking device now I'm stuck in the code of Atmel AVRmega2561, which is supporting with flash memory.

Please advise from where should I start.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You'll have to explain where you're stuck and what your thinking is so far.  Questions like this hardly get answered, because there's not really a specific question to answer.

Comment: Yes. "where do I start" is very general, and you haven't given much specifics on what exactly you've tried so far. Mostly questions like this might not even get an answer - for future questions, show us the code you've tried, and the problems you've encountered (eg the error messages) and ask for specific help with each error you have received.

Answer (score 0):

Start by learning a bit about the [Kalman Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), which will allow you to filter the GPS data.

To help more, we would need to see the circuits and know what you have tried and/or what your experience is.

Comment: Modern GPS chips will do that filtering for you. You can pretty much take their output at face value and throw it directly at your business logic.

Comment: They have all the gyros etc in them?

Comment: Eh, no, but gyro's are unrelated to Kalman filters (or position in general, usually - the normal use is heading/bearing). Accelerometers are the one dubious bit, but considering modern GPS accuracy you ignore the accelerometer as long as the GPS fix is good.

Comment: My mind went blank on accelerometers. GPS is still only accurate to 100 metres though, right?

Comment: Standard deviation is ~2 meters. Galileo (European GPS) will push it to 1 meter. (It's good enough for my employer to count how many lanes a highway has: the GPS traces of cars on different lanes are sufficiently distinct)